# Windows curl string formatting

Tags: string, windows, curl, terminal, escaping

I am trying to use curl to make an HTTP POST request.

The request contains some environment variables. Here is the command:

```
curl -X POST -u username:pass -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"fields\": { \"project\": { \"key\": \"myproject\" }, \"summary\": \"${var1.name} - ${var2.name}\", \"description\": \"Testing testing!:\n${url}\", \"issuetype\": { \"name\": \"Task\" }}}" http://myurl.com/rest
```

The information is sent, but the `${var1.name}` and `${var2.name}` are being sent as literal strings and not as their actual values.

The command is run on windows so that is why I am escaping the quotes. Could that be a problem as to why they're being sent as strings?

Comment: Windows environment variables are deferenced as `%va1%` and `%var2%`.  Can you provide more information about where you're running this?  e.g. Visual Studio Postbuild, or cmd shell, or powershell?

Comment: This is being run in a cmd shell on a windows server

Comment: Its being run in a batch file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows environment variables are deferenced as `%var1%` and `%var2%`.  This works:

```
C:\>set var1.name=test1
C:\>set var2.name=test2
C:\>set var
var1.name=test1
var2.name=test2
```

`curl.exe -X POST -u username:pass -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"fields\": { \"project\": { \"key\": \"myproject\" }, \"summary\": \"%var1.name% - %var2.name%\", \"description\": \"Testing testing!:\n${url}\", \"issuetype\": { \"name\": \"Task\" }}}" http://myurl.com/rest`

Comment: Are you related to Edsger Dijkstra?